# cannot retrieve column titles from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the string values(column titles) from another workbook in row 4 as captions for checkboxes in the workbook where I am running the code. This is what I have so far and it is not working because it is showing the error message "Subscript out of range, run time error 9" Here is what I have. After the error message pops up the line marked below is highlighted. Can anybody help me please. Thank you very much.

```
 Function CallFunction(SheetName As Variant) As Long

 Dim text As String
 Dim titles(200) As String ' Dim titles(200) As String ' Array
 Dim nTitles As Integer
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Dim myCaption As String

 PathName = Range("F22").Value
 Filename = Range("F23").Value
 TabName = Range("F24").Value

 ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & "\" & Filename
 ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

 Set wks = Workbooks("Filename").Worksheets(SheetName).Activate  ' <= Highlights this line ****

 For i = 1 To 199
     If Trim(wks.Cells(4, i).Value) = "" Then
        nTitles = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
        titles(i - 1) = wks.Cells(4, i).Value
 Next

 i = 1

 For Each cell In Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1 + nTitles))

    myCaption = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, i).Value

    With Sheets("Sheet1").checkBoxes.Add(cell.Left, _
        cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        .Caption = myCaption
        .Characters.text = myCaption
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Name = myCaption
    End With

    i = i + 1
 Next
 End Function
```

Comment: Subscript out-of-range typically indicates that a specified Worksheet does not exist in the workbooks `Worksheets` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscript out-of-range typically indicates that a specified Worksheet does not exist in the workbooks `Worksheets` collection.

Otherwise, are you sure that the workbook specified by `FileName` is already open? If not, that will raise the same error.

Ensure that A) the file is already open (or use the `Workbooks.Open` method to open it), and B) ensure that such a worksheet already exists (if not, you will need to create it before you can reference it by name).

**Update**

You have `Workbooks("FileName")` where "Filename" is a string literal. Try changing it to simply `Filename` (without the quotation marks) (**this seems like the OBVIOUS error**).

**Also worth checking:**

I also observe this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
```

If the sheet named by `SheetName` is *active* when the workbook opens, then that line will effectively rename it, so you will not be able to refer to it by `SheetName`, but instead you would have to refer to it by `Worksheets(TabName)`.  ALternatively, flip the two lines so that you *activate* prior to renaming:

```
Set wks = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(SheetName).Activate  
ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
```

For further reading: avoid using Activate/Select methods, they are confusing and make your code harder to interpret and maintain:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

If that is the case, then you could do simply:

```
Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(SheetName).Name = TabName
```

Comment: Ok, I will check A) and B)

Comment: Also possible that `ActiveSheet.Name = TabName` is actually renaming the worksheet that you're expecting to activate a few lines later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I had a mess in my code.